# Вызов Dispose у наследников DbContext в методах CRUD (EFCore 5)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dispose

Использую EFCore 5.0. Обычно делаю наследника от `DbContext` со свойствами `DbSet<T>`, а затем конкретные классы для работы с БД. Но, задумался на счет вызова `Dispose` у наследников `DbContext` в конкретных классах для работы с БД. Суть вопроса, как лучше реализовать классы для CRUD и избежать ошибок?

Я вижу три реализации, но не знаю какая из них наиболее успешная.

```
class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public readonly string ConnectionString = "connection string was here :)";
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base() { }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
    }
        
    public DbSet<Cat> Cats { get; set; }
}
```

```
//1 способ, тут вообще не вызываю Dispose

class CatDataStore : IDataStore<Cat> //интерфейс IDataStore<T> требует реализации CRUD
{
   public async Task<bool> AddItem(Cat item)
   {
      ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
      await context.Cats.AddAsync(item);
      await _context.SaveChanesAsync();
      return await Task.FromResult(true);
   }

   //внизу по аналогии CRUD операции, внутри метода context без вызова Dispose
}
```

```
//2 способ, тут отдельно метод делаю Dispose в котором вызываю _context.Dispose()

class CatDataStore : IDataStore<Cat>
{
   private ApplicationDbContext _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
   public async Task<bool> AddItem(Cat item)
   {
      await _context.Cats.AddAsync(item);
      await _context.SaveChanesAsync();
      return Task.FromResult(true);
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
      _context.Dispose();
   }
}
```

```
//3 способ, тут использую using в теле метода.

class CatDataStore : IDataStore<Cat>
{
   public async Task<bool> AddItem(Cat item)
   {
      using ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
      await context.Cats.AddAsync(item);
      await context.SaveChanesAsync();
      return Task.FromResult(true);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализуйте [IDisposable](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-5.0).

Вот полная реализация `IDisposable`.

```cs
class CatDataStore : IDataStore<Cat>, IDisposable
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    private bool disposed;

    public async Task<bool> AddItem(Cat item)
    {
        await _context.Cats.AddAsync(item);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SupressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (disposed)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException();
            _context.Dispose();
        }
        disposed = true;
    }

    ~CatDataStore() => Dispose(false);
}
```

Теперь вы делать можете так

```cs
using var store = new CatDataStore();
//...
```

Comment: А на счет тех трёх моих вариантов? Чем плох к примеру 2 вариант?

Comment: а чем 3 вариант не оптимален?

Comment: @newbie не знаю.

Comment: @Aarnihauta, я не до конца буду точен, но вроде как конструкция using "нормально" следит за жизненным циклом объекта, если не переусердствовать с ее использованием.

Comment: @Aarnihauta 2 вариант плох тем, что 1) нельзя using 2) непонятно, что Dispose надо вызывать обязательно (или необязательно?) 3 вариант может быть неоптимален по производительности. Так что 1 вариант самый нормальный, если подключений к базе немного и они работают через пул. И все 3 варианта не поддерживают управление временем жизни `ApplicationDbContext`

Comment: @aepot, а в таком случае не оптимальнее просто переопределить нужным способом метод Dispose? И нужно ли это делать, ведь DbContext и так реализует IDisposable, т.о. обрабатывая наследника в т.ч.